# cx_Freeze can't find local package

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash, cx-freeze

I'm using dash to create a standalone desktop app. I want to use cx_Freeze to create an executable for my app.

Here's the `cx_setup.py` file:

```py
import sys

from setuptools import find_packages
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'includes': [
            'cx_Logging', 'idna', 'CustomModule'
        ],
        'packages': [
            'asyncio', 'flask', 'jinja2', 'dash', 'plotly'
        ],
        'excludes': [
            'tkinter'
        ],
        'include_files': [
            'database.ini'
        ]
    }
}

base = 'console'
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables = [
    Executable('server.py',
               base=base,
               target_name='App.exe')
]

setup(
    name='App',
    packages=find_packages(),
    version='0.5.0',
    description='',
    executables=executables,
    options=options
)
```

Here's what the dir looks like:

```
project
│  venv
│
└──src
   │
   └───myPackage
       │   cx_setup.py
       │   Module1.py
       │   Module2.py
```

Module1.py has the following import statement:

```py
from src.myPackage import Module2Class as mc
```

cx_Freeze has no problem building the exe but when it tries to run it throws the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.myPackage'
```

I've tried putting `myPackage` in `cx_setup.py` script but it says that the package doesn't exist. I also used a `setup.py` to install the package using `pip install .` to my `venv`.

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` file in `src`?

Comment: @jpeg No, it is not a package, just a directory to store many packages

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an empty `__init__.py` file in the `src` directory.

The import statement:

```
from src.myPackage import Module2Class as mc
```

implies that the `src` directory is treated as a Python module, however `cx_Freeze` will not recognize it as a module if the `__init__.py` file is missing (even if some IDEs will) and thus will fail to include files from there into the frozen executable.

You can also try to explicitly add `src.myPackage` to the `packages` list of the `build_exe` options:

```
options = {
    'build_exe': {
        ...
        'packages': [
            'src.myPackage', ...
        ],
        ...
    }
}
```

but this might not work either, for the same reason.